# xml attribute and element changes -xslt

Tags: xslt

My XML input is :

```
<TestResponse>
<TestData1/>
<TestData2/>
<TestFinance>
 <Name>TestW</Name>
<id/>
<overDueCounts>
       **<overDueCount days="30">0</overDueCount>**
       <overDueCount days="45">0</overDueCount>
       <overDueCount days="45">0</overDueCo
</overDueCounts>
</TestFinance>
<TestNonFinance>
<Name>TestR</Name>
<id/>
<overDueCounts>
       <overDueCount days="30">0</overDueCount>
       <overDueCount days="45">0</overDueCount>
       <overDueCount days="45">0</overDueCo
</overDueCounts>
</TestNonFinance>
<TestData3/>
</TestResponse>
```

And expected output is to choose only `<TestFinance> and <TestNonFinance>` elements and its child elements combined in `<Aggregate>` parent element.And also,all the attributes in `<TestFinance> and <TestNonFinance>` should be converted into Child elements.  I have bolded this elements and attributes.

Expected Output:

```
  <Aggregate>
    <TestFinance>
    <Name>TestW</Name>
    <id/>
     <overDueCounts>
               **<overDueCount>
               <days>30</days>
               <count>0</count>
               </overDueCount>**
               <overDueCount>
               <days>45</days>
               <count>0</count>
               </overDueCount>
               <overDueCount>
               <days>45</days>
               <count>0</count>
               </overDueCount>
    </overDueCounts>
    </TestFinance>
    <TestNonFinance>
         <overDueCounts>
               <overDueCount> 
               <days>30</days>
               <countdue>0</countdue>
                 </overDueCount>
               <overDueCount>
                  <days>45</days>
               <countdue>0</countdue>
                 </overDueCount>
               <overDueCount>
                  <days>30</days>
               <countdue>0</countdue>
                 </overDueCount>
    </overDueCounts>
    </TestNonFinance>
    </Aggregate>
```

I wrote XSLT as below,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions" exclude-result-prefixes="regexp">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <!-- Template to copy the node without namespaces -->
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="comment()| processing-instruction()" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="TestFinance">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[local-name() = 'TestResponse']/*[local-name() = 'TestFinance']" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="TestNonFinance">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./*[local-name() = 'TestResponse']/*[local-name() = 'TestNonFinance']" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Aggregate>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$TestFinance"/>
              <xsl:copy-of select="$TestNonFinance"/>
        </Aggregate>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

But Result produced is as below.Please note that,I could choose `<TestFinance> and <TestNonFinance>` and combine them under aggregate.But not able to convert attributes into child elements.

```
    <Aggregate>
    <TestFinance>
    <Name>TestW</Name>
    <id/>
     <overDueCounts>
               <overDueCount days="30">0</overDueCount>
               <overDueCount days="45">0</overDueCount>
               <overDueCount days="45">0</overDueCo
    </overDueCounts>
    </TestFinance>
    <TestNonFinance>
    <Name>TestR</Name>
    <id/>
     <overDueCounts>
               <overDueCount days="30">0</overDueCount>
               <overDueCount days="45">0</overDueCount>
               <overDueCount days="45">0</overDueCo
    </overDueCounts>
    </TestNonFinance>
</Aggregate>
```

Please help in converting the attributes into child elements and produce expected output.

Comment: Your expected output combines children of two Test Names (but removes latter): *Test W* and *Test R*. Is that the intention?

Comment: @Parfait ,Thanks for your response.I have added more details into the questions about expected output.Actually I am not able to convert the attributes into child elements as shown in expected output in the same xslt.Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I do not see why you use copy-no-namespaces an variables.

Adding two templates should help:

Special handling for overDueCount:

```
 <xsl:template match="overDueCount" mode="copy-no-namespaces">
      <!-- create an element overDueCount -->
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
           <!-- "call" template  to create a element for each attribute -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="attrtotag"/>
           <!--crate a element count  with value from current node -->
          <count><xsl:value-of select="."/></count>
           <!-- call templates for all child elements -->
          <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="copy-no-namespaces"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Template to create tags from attribute:

```
  <xsl:template match="@*" mode="attrtotag">
      <!-- create a new element with name of current attribute -->
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
          <!-- get the content(value) form the attribute -->
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Output:

```
<overDueCounts>
   **<overDueCount><days>30</days><count>0</count></overDueCount>**
   <overDueCount><days>45</days><count>0</count></overDueCount>
   <overDueCount><days>45</days><count>0</count></overDueCount>
</overDueCounts>
```

Comment: Wow..That worked ..Thankyou very much..Could you please let me know why you have mentioned we dont need to use copy-non-namespaces?Also,I am learning XSLT and I am a beginner in it.I am not able to follow the new two templates you have given.Could you please explain the template a bit in detail please?It would really help me to build xslt myself in future...Kindly help.

Comment: With your copy-non-namespaces node you are removing or avoid creating a namespace prefix. But your input xml (example) does not have a (default) namespace. Therefor it is removing nothing.